# RegEx command to get date

Tags: regex, powershell

Using the following RegEx line in my PowerShell script to pull dates from .txt files. The script is reading and pulling the dates to a .csv file in this format Year,Month,Day,Hour,Min,Sec (2020,06,20,00,50,56).  I'm looking for some guidance on how I can get the date just to show without the commas in this format 2020-06-20

This is how date is listed in .txt files see line that starts with Generated:

```
Node 001 Status Report - Report Version 20200505;
Generated 2020-06-20 00:50:56;
```

Below is portion of the script that's reading and pulling the date:

```
If($_ -imatch 'Generated'){       
   $Date = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join ','
}
```

Comment: Read about named groups. This tutorial covers almost exactly what you want: https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups

I know it's JS, But the regex concept is language-agnostic.

Comment: The line that starts with generated allready has hyphens. Do you mind sharing data you need to transform along with expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) to read each file line by line and pattern match against each line:

```
Select-String -Path a.txt,b.txt -Pattern '^Generated (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})' |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

`Select-String` also adds other benefits. Each pattern match is a `MatchInfo` object that contains the file name, line number that matched, and the line that contains the match. The `-AllMatches` switch will match as many times as possible per input line. The `-Path` parameter accepts an array of files and/or wildcards in the path. The `[1]` index is the first unnamed capture group results, which will be what matches within the first set of `()`.

---

As an aside, I would verify that the `####-##-##` is actually a valid date unless you know that will always be so within your data. You can do this easily if your system culture settings allow for the date format:

```
Select-String -Path a.txt,b.txt -Pattern '^Generated (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})' | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value | Where { $_ -as [datetime] }
}
```

If the culture settings do not allow the format, you will need to use [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=ParseExact(String%2C%20String%2C%20IFormatProvider%2C%20DateTimeStyles)%20method%20parses,the%20order%20specified%20by%20format%20.) or [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1) to test the date.

---

If you must work within your current data format, then you can do the following to extract the date from the comma-delimited string in the required format:

```
If($_ -imatch 'Generated'){       
   $Numbers = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join ','
   $Date = ($Numbers -split ',')[0..2] -join '-'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the expression with `-join ','` for commas, if you want dashes instead, just change that to a dash.

```
If($_ -imatch 'Generated'){       
   $Date = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join '-'
}
```

Comment: Changing the comma to dash worked thank you.  Any suggestions on removing the time portion.

Comment: @user2637664, You can use `$Date = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value[0..2] -join '-'`